# Node restore stream download

Tags: node.js, stream, axios

I am doing a small script to download files with node. The connection I have with the website is very unstable and usually falls several times. My idea is to be able to restore the download if the connection drops at the same point where it was previously.
I use axios and progress-stream:

```
const download = (link, size, localPath, transferred = 0) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    axios({
      url: link,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream'
    })
    .then(response => {

      const writer = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);

      const str = progress({
        time: 100,
        length: size,
        transferred: transferred
      });

      str.on('progress', function(progress) {
        console.log(progress);
      });

      response.data
        .pipe(str)
        .pipe(writer);

      writer.on('finish', resolve);
      writer.on('error', reject);

    })
    .catch(reject);

  });
};
```

When the connection is dropped and I rerun the script, I pass in the parameter 'transferred' the size that the file is currently incomplete but the download starts from 0.
Is there a way to start the download at the point where it was interrupted?

Comment: Does the site you're trying to download supports this kind of download? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range

Comment: Right now I have a local copy of the site mounted with http-server and it is not sending me the range headers. I would have to try the real one when I can. However, wget -c 'url' returns to the download at the previous point. I wish I didn't have to use wget with child_process.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Nick LeBlanc mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150785/node-restore-stream-download#comment102685639_58150785), you need to use the [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) header.

Also note that the `fs.createWriteStream` uses the `'w'` flag by default, which truncates the file if it exists. So you have to set it to `'a'`.

```js
const download = (link, size, localPath, transferred = 0) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    axios({
      url: link,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream',
      headers: {
        Range: `bytes=${transferred}-`
      }
    })
    .then(response => {

      const writer = fs.createWriteStream(localPath, {flags: 'a'});

      const str = progress({
        time: 100,
        length: size,
        transferred: transferred
      });

      str.on('progress', function(progress) {
        console.log(progress);
      });

      response.data
        .pipe(str)
        .pipe(writer);

      writer.on('finish', resolve);
      writer.on('error', reject);

    })
    .catch(reject);

  });
};
```